# How to implement authenticate communication between client and server in WCF?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I need to implement a model, where only an authorized set of clients can use a WCF server. I thought of something along passing an AUTH structure as a param inside each method call. Is this the best method to implement this kind of security, or is there an easier/better way of doing this?
for example i developed and publish the service like below:
http://MyServer.my.com/MyService[^]
By default any any one who know the URL can consume the service.
How i can set specified Set of client can consume the URL.
Also how can we assure no one can change the data between communication.

For eg: client send request for Balance Enquiry service with reponse 500 Rs but some one tried to change it to 500 Rs.

Answer (score 0):

For authentication you can use basic authentication. If using IIS, Web Service users can be local users that have read permissions over the svc file.

For channel security you can use transport mode (https). You will need a certificate for this, but it can be a self signed created by you.

This example sets server and client:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775%28v=vs.110%29.aspx